# PHP - Check if event is overlapping another one

Tags: php, mysql, overlapping

I'm currently developping an event management system for my client but I'm stuck at one place.

For each event, we need to specify the local where the event is happening. This should also be verified.

I need to be able to add an event and check before saving if the event is not overlapping another one in the DB. For example, I got those event in my DB:

```
+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| EVENT NAME |    DATE    | BEGIN_TIME | END_TIME | LOCAL_ID |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| Test 1     | 12/11/2013 | 11:00:00   | 12:00:00 | 250      |
| Test 2     | 12/11/2013 | 10:30:00   | 11:30:00 | 150      |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Now, if I want to add an event from `11:00:00` to `12:00:00` in local `150`, it should give me an error because there's already an event from `10:30` to `11:30` which is in the same time of the other event. BUT, if I add the same event but for the local 200 (for example), it should work because there's no other event at the same time in the local...

I tried to calculate time and date using PHP `range()` and using array methods, but it didn't work. I don't know how I can check that.

Note: I'm using Joomla! 3.1 and I'm able to write my own plugin if needed.

Comment: I think your question might be a bit too broad.  You'll have to be a bit more specific about what you want to test for.  What are the precise rules that you want to use to select your data.  You're saying that you want it to give you an error if there is already an event in this time period... but you haven't provided any code that you have tried so far.  Maybe a code snippet might make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Convert the date and time to a timestamp and then use the method outlined in [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap).

Comment: Can you write custom SQL queries? If so, consider looking into the BETWEEN condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check via SQL - Execute a query to check for any event, matching the `local_id`, that have a events scheduled **between** the proposed dates.

For example

```
 SELECT 
  1  
 FROM 
  events 
 WHERE 
  `local_id` = :local_id 
 AND 
  `date` = :date 
 AND 
  (
    (`begin_time` BETWEEN (:start) AND (:end)
    OR
    (`end_time` BETWEEN (:start) AND (:end)
  )
```

If you get any results then you know that there was a matching event

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, i believe you should just issue an SQL query to check if a row exist within your range using the SQL keyword BETWEEN. And yes your BEGIN and END time columns need to be a native date format and not a string.